# How to generate seats layout for theater screen

Tags: angular, dynamic

I want to generate seats layout when user enter row number 1 and number of seats 12 total 12 div should get created in one row ,When user enter row number 2 and number of seats 13 then 13 div should get crated in next row

```
    import { Seats } from './../../Models/Seats';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { count } from 'rxjs/operators';                 

   @Component({
      selector: 'app-addmovieseats',
      templateUrl: './addmovieseats.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./addmovieseats.component.css']
    })

    export class AddmovieseatsComponent implements OnInit {
      screenNumbar:number;
      seatType:String;
      rowName:String;
      noOfSeats:number;
      seatscount:number []=[];
      seatsArray:Seats[]=[];
      seat : Seats;
      isequaltocolumns:boolean=false;
      customSeatId:String;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {}

      public myclass={
        "row":this.isequaltocolumns,
        "seatI":this.isequaltocolumns
      }

    onClickMe(){

    for(let i=1;i<=this.noOfSeats;i++){

      this.seat = new Seats();
      this.seat.screenNumber=this.screenNumbar;
      this.seat.seatNumber=i;
      this.seat.divId=this.screenNumbar +"_"+this.seatType +"_"+this.rowName+"_";
    this.customSeatId=this.screenNumbar +"_"+this.seatType +"_"+this.rowName+"_";
    this.seat.noOfSeatsperRow=this.noOfSeats;
      this.seatsArray.push(this.seat);
      if(i==this.noOfSeats){
    this.isequaltocolumns=true;
    console.log(this.isequaltocolumns);

      }
    }

     }

        clearArray(){


         }

        }

        <form >  
        <input type="number" id="screenNumbar" name="screenNumbar"  placeholder="enter screen number"  [(ngModel)]="screenNumbar" >

        <input class="form-control"type="text" id="seatType" name="seatType"  placeholder="enter type of seats"  [(ngModel)]="seatType" >
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="rowName" name="rowName"   placeholder="enter rows name" [(ngModel)]="rowName">
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="noofRows" name="noofseats"  placeholder="enter number of seats"  [(ngModel)]="noOfSeats" >

      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="noofseats" name="noofseats"  placeholder="enter number of seats"  [(ngModel)]="noOfSeats" >

      <button (click)="onClickMe()">Submit!</button>

      <button (click)="clearArray()">ClearArray!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
      <div   *ngFor="let seat of seatsArray;let i =index" [ngClass]="{
        'item1':seat.noOfSeatsperRow==i
      }"   >

          <div class="seatI row"
          id="'{{seat.divId}}{{i+1}}'"  [ngClass]="{
            'row':seat.noOfSeatsperRow==i
          }"  >
              {{seat.seatNumber}}{{isequaltocolumns}}
          </div>
      </div>


    </form>
```

Comment: Reactive Forms and FormsGroup and FormsArray may help you here in angular

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I have shared code .I am not able achieve desired output

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya no change in output

Comment: @MahendraShoor Please check I have created a demo.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya your solution will work for me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a `demo` for what you want. As your code is too much long I cannot modify it. So I created a small demo for the same that will help you.

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp4j2k) here, I have created as per your requirement.

> **Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  row: Number;
  seats: Number;
  theatreArr = [];

 onSubmit() {
   // create seats dummy array... 
   const dummySeats = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < this.seats; i++)  {
     dummySeats.push(i);
   }
   this.theatreArr.push({row: this.row, seats: dummySeats});
   this.theatreArr.sort((a, b) => a.row - b.row);
   console.log(this.theatreArr);
 }

}
```

> **HTML**

```
Row Number: <input type="number" class="form-control" id="name" required 
                   [(ngModel)]="row" name="name">
<br/><br/>
No of Seats: <input type="number" class="form-control" id="name" required
                    [(ngModel)]="seats" name="name">
<br/><br/>

<button (click)="this.onSubmit()">Submit</button>


<h3>My Theatre</h3>

<div *ngFor="let theatre of theatreArr" style="display: flex">
    <div *ngFor="let seat of theatre.seats" style="margin-left: 10px; background: lightgray; width: 30px; height: 20px; text-align:center ">
      {{seat}}
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I want to create a seat layout for a theater screen  as each screen have different seat structure.suppose in first row there are 20 seats, in  second row there are only 15 seats and in third row having 20 seats.I want to store this layout in database.Which approach should i follow to achieve this goal